# Mono 3.0 Preview - monodoc monodoc-browser issue

Tags: 13.04, mono

I have a Ubuntu 13.04 box and I'd like to get Mono 3.0 installed.  I found this blog-post here by one of the developers for the Ubuntu Mono group:

https://www.meebey.net/posts/mono_3.0_preview_debian_ubuntu_packages/

However, when I tried to do it, I got the following error at the end of the ***apt-get install mono-complete*** command:

```
Processing triggers for monodoc-browser ...
generating monodoc search index...
grep: /etc/gre.d/*.conf: No such file or directory

Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Monodoc.EditMerger' from assembly 'monodoc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Monodoc.EditMerger' from assembly 'monodoc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'.
```

I don't believe this to be a show-stopper (maybe someone can enlighten me).  It seems this is a common issue for those that compile it, but I'm using a package.  In case it's important, this is a minimal installation without any form of desktop (so I don't think I could use monodoc-browser anyway).

Comment: For those curious, I ended up just building the latest Mono on my own using this awesome guide: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13424880/155110